# Escaping characters in linux for a buffer overflow

Tags: escaping, hex, ascii, buffer-overflow

So we have a lab where we need to perform a buffer overflow on a program.  I already found that GCC has buffer overflow protection and I found that when you compile it, you have to disable it using the -fno-stack-protector flag.  After I got past that, i disassembled the code using gdb and found that i want to redirect the program to the address 0x4005b1.

However when i enter user input, how do i enter the hex value of b1 in ASCII?

When the program prompts for user input is there a way to escape the b1 value.  something similar to:
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@^E\xb1  .  Normally when I just compiled the program the address would start close to 0x040000, but when i use the -fno-stack-protector is starts at a much later address and that is why i need to redirect the return address to 0x4005b1.  If there isn't a way to enter b1, what are some alternative ways to get around this?  Could I somehow link the program to start at a particular address and if so, how is that done?  Any other help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you start your program with a bunch of nops, then you have some flexibility on the bottom byte of the address.

Entering special characters varies depending on the reader and line buffer code you are using.  GNU readline, for example, uses a Compose key to enter special characters.